# How to check whether ManytoMany has values before saving Model?

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many

Let's say I have two classes/models: `Hand` and `Finger`. Imagine that the fingerprint is a TextField and a Hand has an unknown number of Fingers, in the `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Hand(models.Model):
    smoothness = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ])
    fingers = models.ManyToManyField('Finger')
    num_fingers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    has_thumb = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.num_fingers = check_num_finger() # How do I do that?
        if check_has_thumb(): # How do I do that?
            self.has_thumb = True 
        super(Hand, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Finger(model.Model):
    is_a_thumb = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fingerprint = models.TextField()
```

The new Hand is added through the `admin.py` like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Hand, Finger

@admin.register(Finger)
class FingerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [('Finger', {'fields': ['is_a_thumb','fingerprint']})]
    list_display = ('is_a_thumb', 'fingerprint',)

@admin.register(Hand)
class HandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [('Hand', {'fields': ['smoothness']},
                 ('Fingers', {'fields': ['fingers']}]
```

And when saving the `Hand`, we need to check how many fingers are related to the Hand when initialized. And also access the `is_a_thumb` field inside the Finger model to populate/relate `has_a_thumb` from the Hand.

- **How do I access `is_a_thumb` from each`Finger` such that if there's one Finger that `is_a_thumb`, it changes the `Hand`'s value of `has_a_thumb` before saving**
- **How do I access the no. of `Finger`s assigned to the `Hand`, so that I can update `num_fingers` before saving?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it `before` your object get saved. And I don't think this is the right way. I believe what you need to do is to listen for a [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal and update your hand.

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def fingers_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    #sender     Hand.fingers.through (the intermediate m2m class)
    #instance   hand (the Hand instance being modified)
    #action     "pre_add" (followed by a separate signal with "post_add")
    #reverse    False (Hand contains the ManyToManyField, so this call modifies the forward relation)
    #model      Finger (the class of the objects added to the Hand)
    #pk_set     finger_ids beign added (when post_add its a set of all,  not the new ones only, but all)
    #using      "default" (since the default router sends writes here)
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_add':
        hand = kwargs['instance']
        hand.num_fingers = hand.fingers.count() #or len(kwargs['pk_set'])
        hand.has_thumb = hand.fingers.filter(is_a_thumb=True).exists()
        hand.save()

m2m_changed.connect(fingers_changed, sender=Hand.fingers.through)
```

*Note: Btw i'm not sure if M2M is the right relation here. Yes a hand can have many fingers, but one finger should belong to one hand only? If that's True then mb you need to change the relation to One-to-Many (Finger having a FK to Hand).*

Comment: Thanks, that works! But is it a very expensive operation to keep the signals on and checking whether the hand is being saved all the time?

Comment: Is there a way to check that only when `Hand.save()` is called?

Comment: AFAIK, `Hand.save()` don't have access to `M2M relations`, only the `form` has. So another approach would be to set on `form.save()`, with `commit=False`, and then inspect what's inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) is django documentation about working with ManyToMany fields. And [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) documentation for m2m_changed signal. I think you should use it here. I never use this signal in practice but as I understand the code should look like this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

class Hand(models.Model):
    smoothness = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ])
    fingers = models.ManyToManyField('Finger')
    num_fingers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    has_thumb = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Finger(model.Model):
    is_a_thumb = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fingerprint = models.TextField()


def fingers_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    instance.num_fingers = instance.fingers.count()
    if instance.fingers.filter(is_a_thumb=True):
       instance.has_thumb = True
    instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(fingers_changed, sender=Hand.fingers.through)
```

By the way, I think you have mistake in your code when calling super inside the save method. In this example you should use Hand instead of Sentence.

Comment: `self.fingers.count()` won't work, it runs into value error.

Comment: If there is no instance of `Hand` before saving, `self.fingers` will throw a `ValueError`, i.e. `ValueError: "<Hand: Hand object>" needs to have a value for field "hand" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: In the documentation you've linked, the `Hand` already exists in the DB after being saved once before the `object.relatedFiled.count()` works =(

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. I have updated my code using m2m_changed signal.

Comment: Thanks Eduard! The signal documentation link was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `hand.fingers.count()` in order to know the number of fingers of your object.